# can a table be selected in an sql query to group the result

Tags: mysql

hello i just wanted to know is it possible to select the table name in an sql query as part of your result 
so for example when using UNION to join 2 tables can you specify where each result is coming from because so far i have had to add an extra column called `type` to each table to specify and it just seems there could be a better way

```
SELECT id, name, type
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, type
FROM table2
LIMIT 20`
```

result =
id, name, type
id, name, type

but i want to still have the type/table name without selecting it or even having it in my table

pleas let me know if this is possible or if this is the only way to do it ether way thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, name, type, 'table1' AS FromWhichTable
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, type, 'table2'
FROM table2
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: it worked perfectly but if i can trouble you for how i would go about selecting it for php to display

Comment: @user2148712 You will expect a new column with the name `FromWhichTable` in your php code chose it inside the `while` loop to display it, something like `echo $row['FromWhichTable']`